# Dockerfile not waiting for the above command to execute

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, docker-compose, astrojs

I'm trying to create a build files in a docker container of image `node:18-alpine3.17` and have attached the Dockerfile and this docker file is called from docker-compose.yml file and while building the files I'm encountering this error. The framework I'm using is astrojs

Dockerfile

```
# Base image
FROM node:18-alpine3.17

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the package.json and package-lock.json files to the working directory
COPY package*.json ./

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install

# Copy the project files to the working directory
COPY . .

# Build the app
RUN npm run build

# Remove development dependencies
RUN npm prune --production

COPY dist /usr/share/nginx/html
```

If you see the docker-compose file

```
version: '3'

services:
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    volumes:
      - frontend-data:/usr/share/nginx/html

  backend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    environment:
      - DEBUG=0
      - ALLOWED_HOSTS=nginx,localhost,127.0.0.1
      - SECRET_KEY=django-Super-secret-key
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    volumes:
      - static_data:/vol/web
    depends_on:
      - db
    

  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  nginx:
    build: 
      context: ./nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - frontend-data:/usr/share/nginx/html/frontend
      - static_data:/vol/static
    depends_on:
      - frontend
      - backend

volumes:
  db-data:
  frontend-data:
  static_data:
```

so for this I'm getting this error

```
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                           0.0s
 => CANCELED [nginx internal] load metadata for docker.io/nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged:1-alpine                                        0.1s
 => [frontend internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:18-alpine3.17                                                        0.0s
 => [frontend 1/8] FROM docker.io/library/node:18-alpine3.17                                                                          0.0s
 => [frontend internal] load build context                                                                                            0.0s
 => => transferring context: 54.36kB                                                                                                      0.0s
 => CANCELED [backend internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.8-alpine                                                 0.0s
 => CACHED [frontend 2/8] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                0.0s
 => CACHED [frontend 3/8] COPY package*.json ./                                                                                       0.0s
 => CACHED [frontend 4/8] RUN npm install                                                                                             0.0s
 => CACHED [frontend 5/8] COPY . .                                                                                                    0.0s
 => CACHED [frontend 6/8] RUN npm run build                                                                                           0.0s
 => CACHED [frontend 7/8] RUN npm prune --production                                                                                  0.0s
 => ERROR [frontend 8/8] COPY dist /usr/share/nginx/html                                                                              0.0s
------
 > [frontend 8/8] COPY dist /usr/share/nginx/html:
------
failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: "/dist" not found: not found
```

So in this case the astroJS will create folder called dist and store the build files there and I had deleted the dist files and node_modules directory and tried to execute the docker compose and I'm getting this error. Another case is if I created an empty directory dist then the nginx is throwing 403 error and tried to navigate to the volume and it's empty.

I've even tried adding `RUN mkdir dist` before npm install but still the error occurs. Even though removed images volume and running containers in log why do I see cached?

Comment: When you build a Dockerfile it creates a file system layer, when you mount, it overwrites it with mount. The order in which this happens, is not guaranteed. So most likely it's just an empty folder. To debug this, try changing named mounts to local file mounts and check what's in there.

Comment: did you try your initial `workdir` full path `/app/dist` ?

Comment: @M-Raw yeah no luck on that

Comment: @swamper maybe the build directory is named something else like `/build`  check the configs for that, if it doesn't, just build the container up to that point without the final step, get inside it and see how the directories are being structured inside the volume

Comment: @M-Raw Got it resolve there is an answer I tried it and tried to mount the volume in Dockerfile and it got worked. btw Thanks, M-Raw

Answer (score 0):

`COPY` copies from the host's file system to the Docker image.

To copy from the image file system to another location in the image file system, you can use `RUN cp` like this

```
RUN cp dist /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Comment: But is if you see the destination folder is a volume and I tried this and gave this error 
` => ERROR [8/8] RUN cp -R dist /usr/share/nginx/html                                                                                      0.3s
------
 > [8/8] RUN cp -R dist /usr/share/nginx/html:
#0 0.297 cp: can't create directory '/usr/share/nginx/html': No such file or directory
------
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c cp -R dist /usr/share/nginx/html]: exit code: 1`

Comment: That's because you're using a `node` image, but `/usr/share/nginx/html` is a Nginx directory that doesn't exist in the node image.

Comment: Got it resolved! I'm aware that it's node image but I wanted to mount the volume. Thanks for the answer Hans